# User Info only has user_id

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm currently integrating the PayPal REST API into my iOS app and I need to use the login with Paypal to fetch some information about the user.

I've gotten as far as requesting the information using the access token with identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid and with the access token I pass in, the most I get in the response is a user_id field. I must be missing something simple, but how do I get the other information to show up? I set the scope for the PayPalProfileSharingViewController to include Email, Profile, and Address, in addition to openID and futurePayments. My app in the developer dashboard also has the profile information checked as fields I'd like to query. I've tried both sandbox and production environments. But I only ever get user_id in the response.

Relevant code:

```
NSSet *scope = [NSSet setWithArray:@[kPayPalOAuth2ScopeOpenId, kPayPalOAuth2ScopeFuturePayments, kPayPalOAuth2ScopeEmail, kPayPalOAuth2ScopeProfile, kPayPalOAuth2ScopeAddress]];

PayPalConfiguration *config = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
config.merchantName = @"My Sample App";
config.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
config.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

PayPalProfileSharingViewController *sharingVC = [[PayPalProfileSharingViewController alloc] initWithScopeValues:scope configuration:config delegate:self];
```

And the request to get the access tokens (this part works, I'm pretty sure):

```
- (void)fetchAccessTokenWithAuthToken:(NSString *)authToken
{
    if (authToken && self.currentState == DFMPayPalManagerFetchingStateNone) {
        self.currentState = DFMPayPalManagerFetchingStateFetchingRefreshAccessToken;

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@/v1/oauth2/token", kPayPalProductionBaseURL]]];
        NSMutableDictionary *requestHeaders = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [requestHeaders setObject:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
        NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", kPayPalProductionClientID, kPayPalProductionSecret];
        [requestHeaders setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [[authString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]] forKey:@"Authorization"];
        NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code=%@", authToken];
        NSData *bodyData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
        [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:requestHeaders];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (connection) {
            self.userInfoResponseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        }
        else {
            // Error?
            NSLog(@"Connection failed!");
            self.currentState = DFMPayPalManagerFetchingStateNone;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the code to fetch the info using the access token:

```
- (void)fetchUserInfoWithAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken
{
    if (accessToken && self.currentState == DFMPayPalManagerFetchingStateFetchingRefreshAccessToken) {
        self.currentState = DFMPayPalManagerFetchingStateFetchingInfo;

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid", kPayPalProductionBaseURL]]];

        NSMutableDictionary *requestHeaders = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [requestHeaders setObject:@"application/json" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
        [requestHeaders setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", accessToken] forKey:@"Authorization"];

        [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:requestHeaders];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (connection) {
            self.userInfoResponseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        }
        else {
            // Error?
            NSLog(@"Connection failed!");
            self.currentState = DFMPayPalManagerFetchingStateNone;
        }
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
2015-03-19 18:19:32.944 SampleApp[14675:209851] User Info received: {
"user_id" = "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/***";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First off, for security reasons, you should not use the Client Secret directly from the mobile device.  Getting the user information should be done from your server.  Secondly, can you provide a debug_id so that I can take a look at what may be going wrong?

Comment: Ah, it seems like a delay issue? Maybe the permissions need time to propagate, as they show up now when they didn't show up yesterday, and I haven't changed anything.

Comment: As for client using the secret, I'm just testing the flow for now. Ultimately, the server will be the one making the call.